# LINQ: Select Post with multiple Tags

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find all Posts contains all selected tags.

My current code returning posts containing all selected tags AND posts containing some of selected tags.

Here is my function. I appreciate your help.

Sample Database structure

Tables

[Post]
 - Id
 - Title
 - Body

[PostTag]
 - Id 
 - PostId
 - TagName

So [Post] to [PostTag] got One-to-Many relationship with PostId as foreign key.

```
public static IEnumerable<Post> getPostContainsAllTags(IEnumerable<string> _SelectedTags, 
                                                           int numPosts)
{
    using (MaplePrimesDataContext dc = new MaplePrimesDataContext(_connectionString))
    {

        var tagPosts = (from p in dc.Posts
                        join t in dc.PostTags on p.Id equals t.PostId
                        where p.Status == 1 && _SelectedTags.Contains(t.Name)
                        orderby p.DateAdded descending
                        select p).Take(numPosts).ToList();
        return tagPosts;
    }
}
```

Comment: A part from your question I recommend  you to change you database structure. With you model if you have two posts with c# tag, you will have two PostTag c#. It's better to do many to many approach

Comment: I have a Tag Table and didn't put it here for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

I would also change the database structure to not duplicate the tag Name in `PostTag` table

This works and easy to undestand:

```
var tagPosts = dc.Posts.Where(post => post.Status == 1);

foreach (var selectedTag in _SelectedTags)
{
    tagPosts = tagPosts.Where(post => post.PostTags.Any(tag => tag.Name == selectedTag));
}

return tagPosts.OrderByDescending(p => p.DateAdded).Take(numPosts).ToList();
```

This also works and is quite a bit faster

```
var selectedTagIds = dc.Tags.Where(tag => _SelectedTags.Contains(tag.Name)).Select(x => x.TagId);

var tagPosts = dc.Posts
    .Where(post => post.Status == 1)
    .Where(post => 
      !(from selectedTag in selectedTagIds
        join tag in post.PostTags on selectedTag equals tag.TagId into postTags
        from tag in postTags.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where tag.TagId == null
        select 1).Any());

return tagPosts.OrderByDescending(p => p.DateAdded).Take(numPosts).ToList();
```

The difference here is that we create a database collection `selectedTagIds` first and then use it to do a left join (which is very ugly in LINQ -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)

It works because if a post doesn't have a tag, then the left join of that posts tags and selected tags will have a row without a post tag.

Comment: I tried this approach. We can't use ".Any" for local collections. LINQ only allowed ".Contains" for Local collections.

Comment: then try the second approach I've added, I thought of it later

Comment: I have a separate Tag table and I do an another Join with PostTag table. But I removed it here for simplicity of the problem.

Comment: If you PostTag has a foreign key to Tag table, then all you need to do change is `tagPosts.Where(post => post.PostTags.Any(tag => tag.Tag.Name == selectedTag));`

Comment: .Any is not allowed in the Database operation thru LINQ

Comment: @ParvSharma you are incorrect. `Any()` works if used on a database collection

Comment: yeah just checked it does.. im missing this for long now.

Answer (score 0):

```
dc.Posts.Select
.Join(p=>p.Id, dc.PostTags, (p, pt)=>new{Post = P, PostTag = pt})
.Where(o=>SelectTags.Contains(o.PostTag))
.GroupBy(o=>o.Post, o=>o.PostTag)
.Select(g=>new{Post=>g.Key, Count=>g.Count()})
.Where(o=>o.Count == SelectTags.Count())
.Select(o=>o.Post)
.OrderByDescending(o=>o.DateAdded)
.Take(numPosts)
.Tolist()
```

**Note** - i have just typed it here and might not be the optimum way

What iam doing here is that i am selecting
1. Selecting Tags with Post Tags
2. Filtering out all the records With are not in the SelectedTags List
3. Then Grouping by Product to make an `Enumerable` of `objects` With Post as their `key` and `(No of Tags)` as the `value`.
4. Then again Filtering out all the records With `(Count Of Tags)` != `(Count of SelectedTags)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have another Tag table with all the available tags, you might consider using a simple Count:

```
var postsIds = (from p in posts
    join t in postTags on p.Id equals t.PostId
    group p by p.Id into grp
    where grp.Count() == tags.Count()
    select grp.Key).ToList();
```